# Restrict user to certain tables in SQL

Tags: sql, azure

We have a azure based SQL Server instance that we are wanting to create a user who would only have SELECT access to two tables on a database that has many more tables. Is this possible? If so is there a guide I can follow to accomplish this?

Comment: Are your users Azure AD users or SQL DB users?

Comment: Yes it's possible. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226881/azure-sql-database-grant-select-on-certain-tables

Comment: @GauravMantri we are wanting to do this with SQL DB users if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> **Restrict user to certain tables in SQL**

You can use the **SQL GRANT statement to grant SQL SELECT, and other privileges on tables**.

```sql
CREATE USER demouser 
WITH PASSWORD = 'demopa@ssword1234'; 

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.student TO demouser
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Airlines TO demouser

execute as user = 'demouser'
select * from student
select * from Airlines
REVERT;
```

- Execution

Granted SELECT permission to user `demouser` on `Airlines` and `student` table.
[image]

`demouser` user has no access to `mydata` table

[image]